# Error when trying to connect to openfoam repository in lubuntu and unable to install openfoamXYZ-default

Tags: ubuntu, installation, openfoam

Using latest stable lubuntu: 23.04

used: curl -s https://dl.openfoam.com/add-debian-repo.sh | sudo bash

run into issues with sudo apt-get update or install openfoamxyz-default

Here's what happens when I run update:
Err:8 https://dl.openfoam.com/repos/deb lunar Release
404  Not Found [IP: 82.71.205.33 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.openfoam.com/repos/deb lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Tried also adding repository via wget. Shows repository in the software sources. Tried deleting and repeating getting repository. Also can install openfoam without a version

https://openfoam.org/download/11-ubuntu/

as opposed to https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/precompiled/debian

the former instructions resolved the issue with the first step and I was able to install openfoam11

However, openfoam11 incorporates paraview in a way that I did not prefer and does not work in this setup as a seperate issue. So this remains unresolved. In noticed that the repo says lunar vs luna in https://dl.openfoam.com/repos/deb/dists/

not sure what I can do to fix that it says lunar in distribution or if this doesn't matter as the release is lunar lobster...

Comment: Found a workaround and downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openfoam/files/repos/deb/dists/luna/main/pool/2212_230612/binary-amd64/openfoam2212-default_2212.230612-1_amd64.deb/download
But that doesn't resolve why the original instructions didn't work for me/why I cant use the repo.

Comment: Though I apparently don't have the right dependencies so just going to stick with working with openfoam11 for now though that's different and I still get errors in paraview of Mesa warning: Window 41943049 has no colormap!

Mesa warning: Window 41943052 has no colormap!

Mesa warning: Window 41943062 has no colormap!

Comment: I gave up on 23.04 and went back to Jammy Jellyfish. No issues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a mistake in the repositories with '*luna*' instead of '*lunar*' for the 23.04 distro name. It has since been corrected.